# Help to understand and fix this entity error message

Tags: entities

I get this error message:

> Error: Notice: Undefined index: label en EntityDefaultMetadataController::bundleOptionsList() (línea 113 de/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/rooms/sites/all/modules/entity/entity.info.inc).**

The line causing the error message is contained in the following function:

```
 /**
   * A options list callback returning all bundles for an entity type.
   */
  public static function bundleOptionsList($name, $info) {
    if (!empty($info['parent']) && $type = $info['parent']) {
      $entity_info = $info['parent']->entityInfo();
      $options = array();
      foreach ($entity_info['bundles'] as $name => $bundle_info) {
        /* LINE 113 */ $options[$name] = $bundle_info['label']; /* LINE 113 */
      }
      return $options;
    }
  }
```

I don't know what other information I can include in this question because I have no idea what the cause could be. I think it is related to the Entity module because the file is inside Entity module.

Why am I getting that notice message? Is there a way to stop getting it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the code of the Entity module, I noticed that the `$info['parent']->entityInfo()` method is the one defined in [entity.inc](http://drupalcode.org/project/entity.git/blob_plain/refs/heads/7.x-1.x:/includes/entity.inc), and it returns the value obtained from [entity_get_info()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/entity_get_info/7). The reason you are seeing that error is that there is a module defining an entity type and which forgets to define the label for its bundles. The core modules always define the label for their bundles.

```
  /**
   * Set up the object instance on construction or unserializiation.
   */
  protected function setUp() {
    $this->entityInfo = entity_get_info($this->entityType);
    $this->idKey = $this->entityInfo['entity keys']['id'];
    $this->nameKey = isset($this->entityInfo['entity keys']['name']) ? $this->entityInfo['entity keys']['name'] : $this->idKey;
    $this->statusKey = empty($info['entity keys']['status']) ? 'status' : $info['entity keys']['status'];
  }

  /**
   * Returns the info of the type of the entity.
   *
   * @see entity_get_info()
   */
  public function entityInfo() {
    return $this->entityInfo;
  }
```

The Rooms module should give a value for the *label* property for its bundles, or the Entity module should not assume the label is always given. I don't see anything that says the bundle label is always present, even though I suspect it is a required property.

Answer (score 0):

In the preceding line you use a variable `$name => $bundle_info` to use in the iteration, but do not use it.  Instead you use `$name`.  I would drop the array reference ( `=> $bundle_info`) in line 112

```
foreach ($entity_info['bundles'] as $name)
    $options[$name] = $bundle_info['label'];
```

Comment: `$bundle_info` is used, in `$options[$name] = $bundle_info['label'];`.

Comment: I see.  Everyday another lesson learned.